# Simple way to check if code is jquery 3.x compliant?

Tags: jquery

We've been given the task of upgrading a large site to jquery 3.x from 1.11, this site has a lot of js/jquery based 3rd party plugins and is approx 5 years old. I've worked through the console and managed to resolve any errors that cropped up there but there's still a few areas where we're not getting expected behaviour.

Are there any easy ways I can just paste this code into something and have it highlight any areas that are deprecated/ no longer exist in jquery 3.x? I was thinking like a website or something.

It's obviously going to be very time consuming going through each line of code and comparing it to the upgrade guide to see if it's still supported.

Comment: Have you tried [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)?

Comment: Thanks will have a look at that - seems like it patches the gaps then informs you where.